# Delete records in an efficient way

Tags: oracle

I've two tables say STOCK and ITEM. We have a query to delete some records from ITEM table,

```
delete from ITEM where item_id not in(select itemId from STOCK)
```

And now I've more than 15,00,000 records to delete, the query was taking much time to do the operation.

When I searched, I found some efficient ways to do this action.

1. One way:

   CREATE TABLE ITEM_TEMP AS
   SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE item_id in(select itemId from STOCK) ;

   TRUNCATE TABLE ITEM;

   INSERT /*+ APPEND +*/ INTO ITEM SELECT * FROM ITEM_TEMP;
   DROP TABLE ITEM_TEMP;
2. Secondly instead of truncating just drop the ITEM and then rename the ITEM_TEMP to ITEM. But in this case I've to re create all the indexes.

Can anyone please suggest which one of the above is more efficient, as I could not check this in Production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct approach depends on your environment, here.

If you have privileges on the table that must not be affected, or at least must be restored if you drop the table, then the INSERT /*+ APPEND */ may simply be more reliable. Triggers, similarly, or foreign keys, or any objects that will be automatically dropped when the base table is dropped (foreign keys complicate the truncate, of course).

I would usually go for the truncate and insert method based on that. don't worry about the presence on indexes on the table -- a direct path insert is very efficient at building them.

However, if you have a simple table without dependent objects then there's nothing wrong with the drop-and-rename approach.

I also would not rule out just running multiple deletes of a limited number of rows, especially if this is in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Best way from used space (and high watermark) and performance is to drop table and then rename `ITEM_TEMP` table. But, as you mentioned, after that you need to recreate indexes (also grants, triggers, constraints). Also all depending objects will be invalidated.

Some times I try to delete by portions:

```
begin
  loop
    delete from ITEM where item_id not in(select itemId from STOCK) and rownum < 10000;
    exit when SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0;
    commit;
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have very high number of rows, it better use partition table , may be List partition on "itemId". Then you can easily drop a partition.
Also if your application could run faster. This need design change but it will give benefit in long run.

Comment: You couldn't partition the table based on the existence of rows in another table though, and partitioning would involve rewriting all the data anyway.

Comment: Sometime this approach is useful to minimize execution times. Obviously the data must be migrated to a new reorganized table and the delete statement must be changed into a loop for dropping/truncating partitions, but there may be a huge improvement when working in this way. I like this

Comment: But how does it work in a case where you would need to partition according to whether a row has a value that exists in another table? It implies that DML operations on STOCK can cause row migration on ITEM to move rows to another partition. Would there just be two partitions? I agree that in general it's very efficient to delete a portion of a table's rows by dropping partitions, but I don't see a case for it here.